# Code not running properly due to javascript getting PHP values and i don't know how to compare them

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<div class="content">
            <h1>Üdvözöllek, <?php echo $nickname; ?>! </h2>
            <h4>Válasszon hetet: </h4>

            <select class="select-selected" id="1" name="het" onchange="checkclass()">
                <option disabled selected value>Hét</option>
                <option value="1"><?php echo $sd->format('m.d')," - ", $ed->format('m.d');?></option>
                <option value="2"><?php echo $sd2->format('m.d')," - ", $ed2->format('m.d');?></option>
                <option value="3"><?php echo $sd3->format('m.d')," - ", $ed3->format('m.d');?></option>
            </select>

        </div >
        <div>

            <a id="class">
                <select class="select-selected" id="2" onchange="checksubject()" name="osztaly">
                <option disabled selected value><?php echo $class; ?></option></select>
            </a>
            <a id="subject">
                <select class="select-selected" id="3" name="tantargy">
                <option disabled selected value><?php echo $subject; ?></option></select>
            </a>
            <a id="bontotte"></a>
            <a id="classtwo"></a>
        </div>

        <script>
    function checkclass() {
        var het = document.getElementById('1').value;
        if(1<=het){
            var onosztaly = 
            '<select class="select-selected" name="osztaly">'+
            '<option disabled selected value><?php echo $class; ?>'+
            '<option value="<?php echo $class1; ?>"><?php echo $class1; ?></option>'+
            '<option value="<?php echo $class2; ?>"><?php echo $class2; ?></option>'+
            '<option value="<?php echo $class3; ?>"><?php echo $class3; ?></option>'+
            '<option value="<?php echo $class4; ?>"><?php echo $class4; ?></option>'+
            '<option value="<?php echo $class5; ?>"><?php echo $class5; ?></option>'+
            '<option value="<?php echo $class6; ?>"><?php echo $class6; ?></option>'+
            '<option value="<?php echo $class7; ?>"><?php echo $class7; ?></option>'+
            '</select>';        
            document.getElementById("class").innerHTML =(onosztaly);
        }
        }
    function checksubject() {
        var sub = document.getElementById('2').value;
        var clas = document.getElementById('2').value;
        if(sub == clas){
            var onsub = '<select class="select-selected" id="2" name="tantargy">'+
            '<option disabled selected value><?php echo $subject; ?></option>'+
            '<option value="<?php echo $subject1; ?>"><?php echo $subject1; ?></option>'+
            '<option value="<?php echo $subject2; ?>"><?php echo $subject2; ?></option>'+
            '<option value="<?php echo $subject3; ?>"><?php echo $subject3; ?></option>'+
            '<option value="<?php echo $subject4; ?>"><?php echo $subject4; ?></option>'+
            '</select>';
            document.getElementById("subject").innerHTML =(onsub);
        }
        }

    </script>
```

So the last one doesn't make it's select box to fill in, like the other one named "osztaly". I think i have a problem with the IF tag in the javascript because the values can't compare :)

Comment: In the onchange tags. You can see them in the upper-side of the code.

Comment: Both your `sub` and `clas` variables fetch `document.getElementById('2').value` and then you compare them. What is the point in comparing the same value to itself?

Comment: I have fixed your code, see my answer

Comment: too many errors in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dickens got the right way to make the code work, here is an example of correct output. Essentially source has some minor errors, which were eliminated here

```js
function checkclass() {
        var het = document.getElementById('1').value;
        if(1<=het){
            var onosztaly = 
            '<select class="select-selected" id="2" onchange="checksubject()" name="osztaly">'+
            '<option disabled selected value>class</option>'+
            '<option value="class1">class1</option>'+
            '<option value="class2">class2</option>'+
            '<option value="class3">class3</option>'+
            '<option value="class4">class4</option>'+
            '<option value="class5">class5</option>'+
            '<option value="class6">class6</option>'+
            '<option value="class7">class7</option>'+
            '</select>';        
            document.getElementById("class").innerHTML =(onosztaly);
        }
        }
    function checksubject() {
        var onsub = '<select class="select-selected" name="tantargy">'+
            '<option disabled selected value>subject</option>'+
            '<option value="subject1">subject1</option>'+
            '<option value="subject2">subject2</option>'+
            '<option value="subject3">subject3</option>'+
            '<option value="subject4">subject4</option>'+
            '</select>';
            document.getElementById("subject").innerHTML =(onsub);
        }
```

```html
<div class="content">
            <h1>Üdvözöllek, nickname! </h2>
            <h4>Válasszon hetet: </h4>

            <select class="select-selected" id="1" name="het" onchange="checkclass()">
                <option disabled selected value>Hét</option>
                <option value="1">date1</option>
                <option value="2">Date2</option>
                <option value="3">Date3</option>
            </select>

        </div >
        <div>

            <a id="class">
                <select class="select-selected" id="2" onchange="checksubject()" name="osztaly">
                <option disabled selected value>Class</option></select>
            </a>
            <a id="subject">
                <select class="select-selected" id="3" name="tantargy">
                <option disabled selected value>Subject</option></select>
            </a>
            <a id="bontotte"></a>
            <a id="classtwo"></a>
        </div>
```

Comment: correct, `id="2" onchange="checksubject()"` is missing in the original code, adding it will sove the issue

Comment: the `date1` `date2` ....etc are all his own PHP variables, he didn't pasted the full code

Answer (score 0):

You have overwritten your own select box via javascript

Change this code

```
 var onosztaly = 
   '<select class="select-selected" name="osztaly">'+
```

To

```
 var onosztaly = 
   '<select class="select-selected" id="2" onchange="checksubject()" name="osztaly">'+
```

it will work, means both the ID of the select box and the change event is lost when date is changed

to be frank your design is not good, there are effective methods to add options and remove options, innerHTML is very old style

the question text shows -- `javascript getting PHP values` -- this understanding is wrong

your entire code rendered as running HTML and given to browser, there is no more PHP in browser, only browser coding you are doing for drop down change

so when you think that are actually reading values from PHP, that is not a correct understanding

you are directly reading HTML components value only in javascript

Comment: I think finally it will stop here: `document.getElementById("class").innerHTML =(onosztaly);` since thre's no such id

Comment: yes yes, nothing is changed from your code, only two attribute in the select box

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't notice `<a id="class">`